# Getting paramMap data from another component that is not in the current route (ActivatedRoute) in Angular

Tags: angular

Here is my code using paramMap within component A with the activatedRoute and it works fine

```
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = <string>params.get('pid');
      
      this.projectService
        .get(this.id)
        .subscribe((project) => (this.project = <Project>project))
    })
  }
```

Now below it, I am trying to get the paramMap from another component B that is not in the activatedRoute and it is therefore returning null values.

```
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe((params) => {
      let id = params.get('categoryId');

      this.categorySub = this.projectService
        .getProjectCategory(id)
        .subscribe((category) => {
          this.category = category;
        });
```

Can anyone give me some clues on what I could do so that I can get access to component B?

Thank you.

Comment: And where does component B live? Sounds to me you need to somehow communicate between components, depending on how they are related, these are some options: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: Thank you for the link. Component A and B are from the same module and are declared in @NgModule

Comment: Well, depending on how they are related you have different options, as presented in the link.